# RequireJS text! plugin and Load timeout

Tags: http, firefox, requirejs

I'm using the text! plugin with RequireJS and Firefox seems to hate my text templates. My code seems to work just fine in Chrome and Safari. Here is the error I get.

```
Error: Load timeout for modules: text!templates/a.html_unnormalized2,
       text!templates/b.html_unnormalized3,
       text!templates/c.html_unnormalized4,    // _unnormalized# <- What is this?
       ...
       text!templates/n.html,    // I don't see _unnormalized here... why?
       text!templates/o.html,
       text!templates/p.html,
       ...
       http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
```

First, what does the _unnormalized# mean? It seems to append itself to the file name for some of my templates but not all. However, all of my templates are listed in the error message.

Looking at the Net inspector, it seems to be downloading the necessary template files.

Answer (score 3):

I think I figured it out part of the mystery, although I'm not sure about the details. I noticed that this error occurs when I'm using Firebug and in the console options, ShowXMLHttpRequests is turned on. By turing this option off, the page loads without a hitch.

What do you think guys, is this a Firebug problem? Or a requireJS issue? I'd love to understand why this occurs.

Comment: This is happening to me nearly a year later. Sorry Firebug. This one is on you. Firefox's dev tools don't throw this error, nor do Chrome's.

Comment: Chrome's do, actually

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if I just disable the "Script" tab of FireBug, I have no more freeze or time out error.

Firefox 27.0.1
Firebug 1.12.7